# Infer type of react prop by sibling prop value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've defined two different `Shop` type:

```
interface BasicShop {
  address: string;
  distance?: number | null;
  name: string;
  thumbnail?: string;
}
interface FullShop {
  address: string;
  categories: string[];
  distance?: number | null;
  keywords: string[];
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
  name: string;
  rating: number;
  reviews: number;
  thumbnail?: string;
}
```

`FullShop` has more fields than `BasicShop`.

I'm trying to define a react component `ShopListItem`, which has its prop types like:

```
type PropType = {
    size: 'sm' | 'md',
    shop: BasicShop | FullShop
}
```

I want the type of `shop` can be determined by the value of `size`. For example, if `size=sm`, than `shop=BasicShop` and `size=md` than `shop=FullShop`. So that I can write the following code
without type error:

```
<ShopListItem size='sm' shop={(object of type BasicShop)} />
<ShopListItem size='md' shop={(object of type FullShop)} />
```

How can I achevie this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use union types for the whole definition instead of for the fields within your "struct" and you'll get a [discriminate union (or ADT)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```js
type PropType =
    { size: 'sm', shop: BasicShop }
  | { size: 'md', shop: FullShop }
```

Comment: I was destructuring the prop in my component. If I access props like `props.size` and `props.shop`, everything works fine!